# Conditional checks in OGNL

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I want to represent the following JSTL code in Object Graph Navigation Language (OGNL).

```
<c:set var="idError"><s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/></c:set>
<c:set var="chkError"><s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/></c:set>
<c:set var="currentPageError"><s:fielderror fieldName="currentPage"/></c:set>

<c:if test="${not empty idError or not empty chkError or not empty currentPageError}">
    <div class="errorblock">
        <s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="currentPage"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

I have tried the following.

```
<s:set var="idError"><s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/></s:set>
<s:set var="chkError"><s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/></s:set>
<s:set var="currentPageError"><s:fielderror fieldName="currentPage"/></s:set>

<s:if test="%{(#idError!=null and #idError!='') or (#chkError!=null and #chkError!='') or (#currentPageError!=null and #currentPageError!='')}">
    <div class="errorblock">
        <s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="currentPage"/>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

This works only for the first conditional check, `#idError!=null and #idError!=''`. The rest of the conditions are never evaluated to true?

What is the correct way to represent the given JSTL code using OGNL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the problem in question but in this case, I was trying to display error messages based on whether a particular field has an error or not.

In this case, since field errors are stored in the `fieldErrors` map, specific field errors can be checked using `<s:if>` like as follows.

```
<s:if test="fieldErrors.containsKey('transporterId') or fieldErrors.containsKey('chk') or fieldErrors.containsKey('currentPage')">
    <div class="errorblock">
        <s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="currentPage"/>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

This is sufficient to suit my requirements.

---

This is also possible by using the following simple conditional check as usual.

```
<s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
    <div class="errorblock">
        <s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="currentPage"/>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

But in this case, I need to check only for a selected fields to see if they have generated some errors and **not** for all the fields which are submitted by a request. Hence, there is a need to check for all those **selected** fields (not all) like the first case.

These selected fields are generally hidden fields or query-string parameters.

Any errors generated by them are displayed at one place in a block whereas any errors generated by the rest of the fields like input components such as `<s:textfield>` are displayed just beside them.